# Online index rebuild?

Tags: coveo

I've used `Solr` for previous Sitecore projects, but I'm looking at Coveo for my latest project.

**Similar to the Solr core swap:** does Coveo provide the ability to rebuild an index, while still maintaining the old version of the index during the rebuild?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coveo will first add the new items and then send a delete order for the older ones.

This mean that you do not need to configure anything in Coveo to be able to query the index while rebuilding.

Versions of Coveo for Sitecore 3.0 prior to December 2014 do not have this feature. Upgrading is the only option.